# Printer will not print .pdf, .png and .ps files on Ubuntu 18

Tags: printing, pdf, brother

I was able to print any type of document initially.  Now and for several weeks **I have not been able to print graphics files, .pdf files  or screen shot files for my desktop or from the internet.  ****I can print any text files that I create via Libre Office Write.**  I am using the printer I have had installed and have used flawlessly in the past.  It is **installed as a USB printer, used locally, and was installed via the Common Unix Printing System (CUPS).**  It is a **Brother printer model HL-L2300D.**  Today was the operating system update installation day.  I saw some CUPS files downloaded for install and thought that maybe my printing problem would go away once I completed the update process, but they did not.  The problems are the same.  I have played around with the printer configuration.  There's not much to change configuration-wise and I have not seen any change in performance.  I am using a Dell computer, which is dual-bootable into Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu 18.  I can print all the same file via Windows 10 with no problem.  Can anyone advise me on what to do, please? I am more of an intermediate user of Linux.

I looked at the print jobs for the printer through the CUPS interface and printed a graphic to see the behavior.  The list of print jobs acted as if I had successfully printed the file AND I had not.  Any advice??  Will I ever print graphics, etc again??  It's as if a message was sent (by CUPS) to the printer to do something and the printer sent a message back saying it had done the job when it had not done the job.

Moved from comment, so it could be `{}` formatted.

```
Jun 19 14:27:16 My Computer Name Here systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jun 19 15:25:28 My Computer Name Here /hpfax[3483]: [3483]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
```

Comment: Access the CUPS interface by pointing a browser to `http://localhost:631`. Or do `service cups status`

Comment: Jun 19 14:27:16 My Computer Name Here systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jun 19 15:25:28 My Computer Name Here /hpfax[3483]: [3483]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip

Comment: I didn't mean to send this last message without adding:        This is the tail end of what I got when I put service cups status in the terminal window command line.  I don't understand why they have "hpfax" in the last line because I don't have and HP fax machine, no HP equipment, no fax machine at all attached, just the printer I describe above.  Can you advise me on the result?

Comment: One or more of the directories in `/var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip` doesn't exist, or has incorrect ownership or permissions.

Comment: Output of `ls -lad /var/spool/cups/` ; `ls -la /var/spool/cups/` ?

Comment: output from ls -lad /var/spool/cups/  -->  drwx--x--- 3 root lp 12288 Jun 19 17:54 /var/spool/cups/                 output from ls -la /var/spool/cups/  --->   ls: cannot open directory '/var/spool/cups/': Permission denied       I don't know why my permission would be denied because I am the sole user of this computer and I set everything up.    Also, I did some digging around and found some newer versions of CUPS.  Can you advise me further in either case - newer version install or repair of something in this version??

Comment: I have the same error message, but everything is running okay regardless. I wish there was a way to resolve the error, but it looks like this is a known issue: [HPLIP: Wrong permissions on /var/spool/cups](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1490321)

On Launchpad, please mark down that this bug affects you.